# OLS in multiple regression for nx1 matrix

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, statsmodels

X is 50x6 matrix and y is a 50x1 matrix

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog = y , exog = X_opt).fit()
regressor_OLS.summary()
```

Instead of showing the summary details it is showing error

*if not np.isfinite(exog_max).all():*

*TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''*

I don't know how to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]

This should be followed by

X_opt=np.array(X_opt,dtype=float)

#will convert entire X_opt into an array of float